# Highcharts drilldown datalabels different from parent

Tags: highcharts

Need some help, how to show parent values with % and child values without %. Thanks in advance.

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty("drilldown")) {
        return this.series.name + ", " + this.y+'%';
    } else {
        return this.series.name + ", " + this.y;
    }
}
        //format: '{point.y:.1f}'
      }
    },
    
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply check if the point has property drilldown. So we need to change your code a little bit:

```
      if (this.point.drilldown) {
        return this.series.name + ", " + this.y + '%';
      } else {
        return this.series.name + ", " + this.y;
      }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/obukypjn/